# Handlebars how to get sibling value inside an object

Tags: handlebars.js, each

ok so iv got an object which looks like this:

```
Magnetim.photos = {
 facebook:{albums: {id:["id1","id2","id3","id4"] , albumName:["n1","n2","n3","n4"]}},
}
```

inside a handlebars template im doing this line of code:

```
<select id="albums-selection">
  {{#each photos.facebook.albums.albumName}}
    <option id="{{photos.facebook.albums.id}}" value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
 {{/each}}
</select>
```

this outputs this result:

```
<option id="id1,id2,id3,id4" value="n1">n1</option>
<option id="id1,id2,id3,id4" value="n2">n2</option>
<option id="id1,id2,id3,id4" value="n4">n3</option>
<option id="id1,id2,id3,id4" value="n4">n4</option>
```

but what i'm trying to achieve is for every name set the id element to its own id, so it looks like this:

```
<option id="id1" value="n1">n1</option>
<option id="id2" value="n2">n2</option>
```

etc..

Comment: I wonder if something like `../id[{{@index}}]` or `../../id[{{@index}}]` or even `photos.facebook.albums.id[{{#index}}]` would work.  The idea is that when you're doing a `#each` of `albumName`, you're at the `n1, n2` level.  If you go up the right number of levels, you can get to the the albums level where you can then go down to `id` and `@index` will give you the same index that your `#each` was currently iterating in the albumName array.  Of course, this would be a lot easier if you fixed your data to put the `n1` and `id1` as separate properties of the same object.

Comment: Or, if you can't do array indexing in handlebars, then maybe the [lookup helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) will work.

Comment: ill try both suggested answers

Comment: both solutions cannot be applied in my case. i'm using meteor which does not support @index.

Comment: Your question ONLY says handlebars.  If you have further limitations than that, then next time put those in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are in the `{{#each}}` statement handlebars provides you with `@index` variable to track the current item index. Knowing this, you should be able to get corresponding item from other array.

So first you need to step outside of your `{{#each}}`, this is done by using `../`, which will move you one level up.

My initial aproach was simply to do something like this

```
{{../albumName.[@index]}}
```

But for some reason that didn't work out. So I wrote the helper to simply grab item from array by index you pass there:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getAlbumName', function(array, id) {
        return array[id];
    });
```

Now your handlebars template will look like this:

```
  <script id="template">
        <select id="albums-selection">
            {{#each id}}           
              <option id="{{this}}" value="{{getAlbumName ../albumName @index}}">
                {{getAlbumName ../albumName @index}}
              </option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    </script>

    <div id="output"></div>
```

And here is the js:

```
var Magnetim = {};
Magnetim.photos = {
    facebook: {
        albums: {
            id: ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"],
            albumName: ["n1", "n2", "n3", "n4"]
        }
    }
};

var source = $("#template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

Handlebars.registerHelper('getAlbumName', function(albums, id) {
    return albums[id];
});

$("#output").html(template(Magnetim.photos.facebook.albums));
```

Final [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feqxever/) with everything in place

Comment: that is really nice answer, i did thought to do a new registerHelper similar to what you wrote , just thought there is something out of the box. in any case this : {{../}} doesn't spouse to get the context to the parent object?? 
i still don't get why i cant iterate an array which is inside an object and then escape the current context and get another elements from another array inside the same object. its simple as doing a for loop for two arrays...

Comment: I was surprised about that too. You can do `{{../albumName}}`, but `{{../albumName.[@index]}}` isn't working for some reason. Don't know if it's bug, or I just don't know something. I guess rising issue on handlebars repo on github, could give replies from handlebars developers